# Get the checkbox in the WPF data grid's column header

Tags: wpf

How to iterate through the column header template of a WPF data grid ?
I want to get the checkbox's content from the data grid's column header template.
My header template is below:

```
  <DataGrid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <CheckBox x:Name="chkbxHeader" Content="{Binding}" 
                                      Loaded="chkbxHeader_Loaded" Unchecked="chkbxHeader_Unchecked" 
                                      Checked="chkbxHeader_Checked" IsChecked="True" Width="100" Height="23" />                               
                           
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.Resources>
```

I want to know which are the checkboxes are checked and unchecked.
By default, all the check box in the grid's column header must be in checked status. I tried to get the content of each checkbox in the loaded event. But the content was not ready at that time.

Comment: Don't. Instead, Bind ischecked. Act in the setter of the public property.

Comment: I have done it.